# how to return a nullable type as the method output?

Tags: c#

here's my code, i'm trying to return temp but it says "cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.an explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

```
 public int? pop(int? i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            int j = (n/2);
            int? temp;
            bool flag1=true;
            while (j>=0)
            {
                if (dstack[j] != null)
                {
                    temp = dstack[j];
                    dstack[j] = null;
                    flag1=false;
                    break;
                }
                j--;
            }
            if (flag1)
                Console.WriteLine("stack 1 is empty:");
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The method signature says you want to return an `int`.  The method implementation says you want to return an `int?`.  The two are not the same thing.  Which do you want to do?

Comment: Use the version-specific tags if you have a version-specific question, don't just add them all when it is version-agnostic.

Comment: @user, now that you've changed the return type of your method, are you sure it's giving you the same error?  Which line is highlighted as failing now?

Comment: @KirkWoll same line, different error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the return type `int?` and adjust your calling code to handle a nullable return type (consider it may not have a value):

```
public int? pop(int? i)
```

The error you have now makes sense.

Alternatively, return `temp.Value`, which is an int, but you need to decide on a default value (in case temp is really null):

```
return temp.HasValue ? temp.Value : -1;
```

---

It actually doesn't make any sense to make temp an `int?`. You have no use for it and by the looks of the method signature you need an `int` in the caller.

What you need is a default value for `temp`. So my final suggestion is to choose a default value that makes sense to you and drop all nullable ints.

Comment: still not working!  now there are two errors second one says "use of unassigned local variable 'temp' "

Comment: @user3927214: Well, does that error say anything to you? Initialize `temp` with a value that makes sense to your algorithm. Or, drop the nullable and make temp a regular int.

Answer (score 0):

Available in C# 8.0 and later, you can use the null-coalescing operator `??` and return int value:

```
return temp ?? -1;
```

It returns temp when not null, or -1 when temp is null.

More information on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)